# streaming media over HTTP

Tags: python, http, web, streaming

I'm writing a web service to stream video (e.g., web cam). I want to know what options do I have.

For example, one naive way I can think of is to periodically fetch a jpeg from the source and display it.

But I also know some media types like mjpeg can be [streamed over the HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#M-JPEG_over_HTTP). However I do not know exactly how that is achieved technically. Any example would be welcome.

UPDATE:

I found the below link, which implements a live video stream over HTTP using mjpeg and python WSGI.

[Streaming MJPEG over HTTP with gstreamr and python – WSGI version (GIST)](https://gist.github.com/2409785)

Comment: this might be helpful http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamserver/?source=recommended

Answer (score 0):

Forget about gstreamer or ffmpeg.

1. create RAM DISK
2. install openCV , within infinite loop with "read()" write each frame into RAM DISK as jpg with Pillow
3. install https://snapcraft.io/mjpg-streamer point to ram disk and enable delete after read.